# Placing a slash in a string

Tags: php

In PHP we have tried to use `str_replace()` to do this.

We have stored in the database `<img src="images/dogtopic.jpg"` and need to insert a `/` before the word images to set the correct path to the image.

We have tried all sorts of combinations to achieve this but to no avail.

Any ideas would really be appreciated

Comment: *We have tried...* Please show us examples.

Comment: $new_str=str_replace("images","/images",$str); But, why you would store path, and HTML tag into database? Rather store just image name, and do the rest in your code/template....

Comment: Why are you storing the full html tag? Is it a scraper that's storing the html? And as @nevermind stated in his comment, it works....[Example](http://www.tehplayground.com/#uhHLlgXCe)

Comment: It was a third party forum software storing users comments/images etc but the image URL's where missing the leading slash.
Sorry guys, I will include code next time
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo str_replace('images', '/images', "<img src='images/dogtopic.jpg'>");
```

Make sure that you post code next time, otherwise nobody will help you